# How do I add numbers together using loops?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-2.x

```
def adding():
    total = 0
    x = 0
    while x != 'done':
        x = int(raw_input('Number to be added: '))
        total = x + total
        if x == 'done':
            break
    print total
```

I cant figure out how to add numbers that a user is inputing, and then stop and print the total when they input 'done'

Comment: `'done'` is not a number.  If you convert every input you get to an integer, you'll never see it.  I suggest you only convert to a number when you're sure that the input is not `'done'`  Use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's yelling at you with a `ValueError` when the user inputs `"done"`? That's because you're trying to cast it as an `int` before checking if it's a number or the sentinel. Try this instead:

```
def unknownAmount():
    total = 0
    while True:
        try:
            total += int(raw_input("Number to be added: "))
        except ValueError:
            return total
```

Alternatively, you can change your own code to work by doing:

```
def unknownAmount():
    total = 0
    x = 0
    while x != "done":
        x = raw_input("Number to be added: ")
        if x == "done":
            continue
        else:
            total += int(x)
    return total
```

But beware that if the user enter `"foobar"`, it will still throw a `ValueError` and not return your total.

EDIT: To address your additional requirement from the comments:

```
def unknownAmount():
    total = 0
    while True:
        in_ = raw_input("Number to be added: ")
        if in_ == "done":
            return total
        else:
            try:
                total += int(in_)
            except ValueError:
                print "{} is not a valid number".format(in_)
```

This way you check for the only valid entry that's NOT a number first (`"done"`) then holler at the user if the cast to `int` fails.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to make it so that if they type anything other than "done" it tells them its an invalid input and try again. Would that be possible using try/ except

Comment: put a try-except in the `else` section

Comment: Thanks again, I tried the code, but when i print the total it comes out to 0.

Comment: @SpicehTuna Don't know how to help you then. I can't replicate that issue. Looks like a copy/paste issue to me.

Comment: Your example is Python 3, while OP uses Python 2.x. Maybe you should change `print` to statement and `input` to `raw_input`.

Comment: @m.wasowski whoops, you're right! I've amended the answer, though it looks like OP figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar questions here, but what the hell. Simplest would be:

```
def adding():
    total = 0
    while True:
        answer = raw_input("Enter an integer: ")
        try:
            total += int(answer)
        except ValueError:
            if answer.strip() == 'done':
                break
            print "This is not an integer, try again."
            continue
    return total

summed = adding()
print summed
```

More fancy take on problem would be:

```
def numbers_from_input():
    while True:
        answer = raw_input("Enter an integer (nothing to stop): ")
        try:
            yield int(answer)
        except ValueError:
            if not answer.strip(): # if empty string entered
                break
            print "This is not an integer, try again."
            continue

print sum(numbers_from_input())
```

but here are some python features you may not know if you are begginer